# Masked SVG element not showing on second line

Tags: svg, text, mask

I use SVG masks to cut out text from a white rectangle and reveal the background behind it. When the text is on one line, everything works perfectly. On mobile, I want to wrap the text and left align it, so I split the text into two elements (but still one SVG).

That's when the problem arises: the second line of the SVG doesn't show. When inspecting it with Chrome, the element is positioned exactly where it's supposed to be, but it's not visible. The same is true for all other browser (haven't checked Internet Explorer yet).

It's supposed to look like this (notice the second line): [screenshot of the intended design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzm2m.png).

I've checked for typos, tried omitting the first line of the SVG (the "Made by" part) and googled extensively - nothing worked. Most questions regarding SVGs not showing refer to dynamically created ones, which doesn't apply in this case. This seems to be a very specific error (most likely on my part).

Please have a look at it and see if you can find the mistake. Thanks!!

Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/connor_baer/pen/yJONxN and here's the code (resize the viewport to see the mobile version):

```css
.header {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465152251391-e94453ee3f5a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=2f3699fc4dbc682fbecdc4fa4d5f6cad') 50% 50% / cover;
}

.header-large {
  display: none;
}

.header-small {
  display: none;
}

.header-text {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media (max-width: 36em) {
  .header-small {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 36em) {
  .header-large {
    display: block;
    width: 32rem;
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header">
    <svg class="header-large" viewbox="0 0 450 75">
      <defs>
        <g id="text-large">
          <text class="header-text" text-anchor="middle" x="225" y="53">Made by Connor.</text>
        </g>
        <mask id="mask-large" x="0" y="0" width="450" height="75">
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="450" height="75" fill="#fff"/>
          <use xlink:href="#text-large" />
        </mask>
      </defs>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="450" height="75" mask="url(#mask-large)" fill="white" fill-opacity="1"/>
      <use xlink:href="#text-large" mask="url(#mask-large)" />
    </svg>
    <svg class="header-small" viewbox="0 0 240 150">
      <defs>
        <g id="text-top">
          <text class="header-text" x="15" y="53">Made by</text>
        </g>
        <mask id="mask-top" x="0" y="0" width="240" height="75">
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="240" height="75" fill="#fff"/>
          <use xlink:href="#text-top" />
        </mask>
        <g id="text-bottom">
          <text class="header-text" x="15" y="128">Connor.</text>
        </g>
        <mask id="mask-bottom" x="0" y="75" width="210" height="75">
          <rect x="0" y="75" width="210" height="75" fill="#fff"/>
          <use xlink:href="#text-bottom" />
        </mask>
      </defs>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="240" height="75" mask="url(#mask-top)" fill="white" fill-opacity="1"/>
      <use xlink:href="#text-top" mask="url(#mask-top)" />
      <rect x="0" y="75" width="210" height="75" mask="url(#mask-bottom)" fill="white" fill-opacity="1"/>
      <use xlink:href="#text-bottom" mask="url(#mask-bottom)" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is that your [mask units](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#Masking) are clearly user space units but the default is objectBoundingBox. I've fixed that below. With the markup you wrote the mask starts way off the bottom of the screen i.e. 75 x the height of the shape.

Also SVG is case sensitive so you want viewBox and not viewbox.

```css
.header {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465152251391-e94453ee3f5a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=2f3699fc4dbc682fbecdc4fa4d5f6cad') 50% 50% / cover;
}

.header-large {
  display: none;
}

.header-small {
  display: none;
}

.header-text {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media (max-width: 36em) {
  .header-small {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 36em) {
  .header-large {
    display: block;
    width: 32rem;
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header">
    <svg class="header-large" viewBox="0 0 450 75">
      <defs>
        <g id="text-large">
          <text class="header-text" text-anchor="middle" x="225" y="53">Made by Connor.</text>
        </g>
        <mask id="mask-large" x="0" y="0" width="450" height="75">
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="450" height="75" fill="#fff"/>
          <use xlink:href="#text-large" />
        </mask>
      </defs>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="450" height="75" mask="url(#mask-large)" fill="white" fill-opacity="1"/>
      <use xlink:href="#text-large" mask="url(#mask-large)" />
    </svg>
    <svg class="header-small" viewBox="0 0 240 150">
      <defs>
        <g id="text-top">
          <text class="header-text" x="15" y="53">Made by</text>
        </g>
        <mask id="mask-top" x="0" y="0" width="240" height="75" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="240" height="75" fill="#fff"/>
          <use xlink:href="#text-top" />
        </mask>
        <g id="text-bottom">
          <text class="header-text" x="15" y="128">Connor.</text>
        </g>
        <mask id="mask-bottom" x="0" y="75" width="210" height="75" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <rect x="0" y="75" width="210" height="75" fill="#fff"/>
          <use xlink:href="#text-bottom" />
        </mask>
      </defs>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="240" height="75" mask="url(#mask-top)" fill="white" fill-opacity="1"/>
      <use xlink:href="#text-top" mask="url(#mask-top)" />
      <rect x="0" y="75" width="210" height="75" mask="url(#mask-bottom)" fill="white" fill-opacity="1"/>
      <use xlink:href="#text-bottom" mask="url(#mask-bottom)" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Had to look up what maskUnits is, as I hadn't come across it before. For anybody else wondering, here's a [description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/maskUnits). Thanks for the help! It works now.